# Cygwin: Parse error before "loff_t" in types.h

Tags: c, cygwin

I tried to "make all" [zebra.tar.gz](http://radagast.se/othello/zebra.tar.gz) under Cygwin. I got this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:440,
                 from /usr/include/zconf.h:364,
                 from /usr/include/zlib.h:34,
                 from getcoeff.c:29:
/usr/include/cygwin/types.h:39: error: parse error before "loff_t"
```

Any Cygwin expert can solve this? I just installed Cygwin today so it's the latest version.

Comment: Oh, MinGW did the job! My problem is solved but I guess this question is still theoretically interesting. =p

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `#define __linux__` line in *getcoeff.c*, which has the effect of disabling the definition of *__loff_t* and various other types in */usr/include/machine/types.h*, perhaps because on Linux those types are predefined in the compiler.

Cygwin of course isn't Linux, even if it aims for compatibility. It's a bug for an application to define a system configuration macro like that, which might well cause trouble on other non-Linux systems too.